# Failing to print duplicates from List of Dictionary

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, duplicates

I'm new to programming but getting the hang of it. But I'm stuck trying to print duplicates from a Dictionary List, which gives me the following error:
[image: My Error Output]

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> Locations = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
        var stringinput = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        string xString = x.ToString();
        string yString = y.ToString();            
        stringinput.Add(xString, yString);

        Locations.Add(stringinput);

        var duplicates = Locations
        .GroupBy(i => i)
        .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
        .Select(g => g.Key);

        foreach (var d in duplicates)
            Console.WriteLine(d);
```

Does any one have any ideas of a solution or a work around to print those duplicates?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Regex;
 
namespace Application
{
    static class EmptyClass
    {
        static void ForEach(this int[] ints, Action<int> action)
        {
            foreach (int i in ints)
                action(i);
        }
 
        static void Main()
        {
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;
            string xString = x.ToString();
            string yString = y.ToString();
            string direction = "north";
 
            List<Dictionary<string, string>> Locations = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
            var stringinput = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            stringinput.Add(xString, yString);
            Console.WriteLine("Insert directions(R1, R2, L3 etc...: ");
            string s = Console.ReadLine();
            string[] words = s.Split(',');
            foreach (string word in words)
            {
                var Rwords = word;
                if (Regex.IsMatch(Rwords, "R"))
                {
                    Regex re = new Regex(@"\d+");
                    Match m = re.Match(Rwords);
 
                    if (direction == "north")
                    {
                        x = x + Convert.ToInt32(m.Value);
                        direction = "east";
                        Console.WriteLine("Your location is (x{0},y{1})", x, y);
                        Locations.Add(stringinput);
                    }
                    else if (direction == "east")
                    {
                        y = y - Convert.ToInt32(m.Value);
                        direction = "south";
                        Console.WriteLine("Your location is (x{0},y{1})", x, y);
                        Locations.Add(stringinput);
                    }
                    else if (direction == "south")
                    {
                        x = x - Convert.ToInt32(m.Value);
                        direction = "west";
                        Console.WriteLine("Your location is (x{0},y{1})", x, y);
                        Locations.Add(stringinput);
                    }
                    else if (direction == "west")
                    {
                        y = y + Convert.ToInt32(m.Value);
                        direction = "north";
                        Console.WriteLine("Your location is (x{0},y{1})", x, y);
                        Locations.Add(stringinput);
                    }
                }
                var Lwords = word;
                if (Regex.IsMatch(Lwords, "L"))
                {
                    Regex re = new Regex(@"\d+");
                    Match m = re.Match(Rwords);
 
                    if (direction == "north")
                    {
                        x = x - Convert.ToInt32(m.Value);
                        direction = "west";
                        Console.WriteLine("Your location is (x{0},y{1})", x, y);
                        Locations.Add(stringinput);
                    }
 
                    else if (direction == "west")
                    {
                        y = y - Convert.ToInt32(m.Value);
                        direction = "south";
                        Console.WriteLine("Your location is (x{0},y{1})", x, y);
                        Locations.Add(stringinput);
                    }
                    else if (direction == "south")
                    {
                        x = x + Convert.ToInt32(m.Value);
                        direction = "east";
                        Console.WriteLine("Your location is (x{0},y{1})", x, y);
                        Locations.Add(stringinput);
                    }
                    else if (direction == "east")
                    {
                        y = y + Convert.ToInt32(m.Value);
                        direction = "north";
                        Console.WriteLine("Your location is (x{0},y{1})", x, y);
                        Locations.Add(stringinput);
                    }
                }
            }
            int Distance = x + y;
            Distance *= -1;
            Console.WriteLine("Calculating distance to HQ......");
            Console.WriteLine("Your location is (x{0},y{1}) wich is {2} Blocks away from Easter Bunny HQ", x, y, Distance, ",");
            var duplicates = Locations
            .GroupBy(i => i)
            .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
            .Select(g => g.Key);
 
            foreach (var d in duplicates)
                Console.WriteLine(d);
 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is because two dictionary objects will not compare for equality even if their content is identical to each other.

Comment: on what criteria you want to find duplicates ?

Comment: Post all relevant code here, external links rot. Questions must stand alone for this reason.

Comment: Why are you storing locations in a dictionary? Dictionaries are for data that has a key and a value, and you use the key to lookup the value. I would define a Coordinate class and make a list of those, or use a Tuple<string,string>. I don't think the compiler understands the concept of a "duplicate" in a dictionary.

Comment: @A.T. when the same x&y have been inputted earlier. So for example when 34,24 has been added to the list, 25,34, and when 34,24 is added to the list for the second time -> that is the duplicates that i want to find.

Comment: @sefe i uploaded the complete code to pastebin. Didn't know that login what required. My apologies.

Comment: @CodeCommisaris If you only store one pair of x-y values in each `Dictionary`, then you are definitely using the wrong data type.  Like Palle said create your own or use `Tuple`

Comment: @PalleDue thanks for your answer, i will look into that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SelectMany` to flatten the key-value-pairs from all dictionaries:

```
duplicates = locations.SelectMany(dict => dict)
                      .GroupBy(kv => kv.Key)
                      .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                      .Select(g => g.Key);
```

You are currently grouping by the dictionary itself. That doesn't work because `Dictionary<tkey,tval>` doesn't override `Equals`+`GetHashCode`. You also don't want to find duplicate dictionaries but duplicate keys.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The weird output is gone and it becomes 0. What could be going wrong?
Or does the code above print when x is the same as y?
The purpose for this code is to get the duplicate locations that have been "visited". For example x34,y24 has been added to the list, x25,y34, and when x34,y24 is added to the list for the second time.

Comment: @CodeCommisaris: well, in your current code there is no duplicate